# LEFT JOIN becomes a implicit join how i fixit?

Tags: mysql, subquery, left-join

This query makes one JOIN instead a LEFT join but I don't know how do it 
whitout the wheres clauses that uses cierre_mensual table:

```
SELECT last_odometro.equipo, IFNULL(SUM(cierre_mensual.recorrido),0) + 
      last_odometro.recorrido AS ultimo_odometro
FROM (
    SELECT *
    FROM `cierre_mensual`
    WHERE mes < '2012-03-01'
    AND `tipo_de_recorrido`
    IN ( 1, 3 )
    GROUP BY `equipo`
    HAVING MAX( mes ) 
) AS last_odometro
LEFT JOIN 
    `cierre_mensual` ON last_odometro.`equipo` = cierre_mensual.`equipo`
WHERE 
        cierre_mensual.mes > last_odometro.mes
    AND cierre_mensual.mes < '2012-03-01'
GROUP BY `last_odometro`.`equipo`
```

The table fields are:
id  equipo  mes     combustible_en_tanque   recorrido   tipo_de_recorrido

1)I want to find recorrido whit the last mes(date) that tipo_de_recorrido are (1,3) 
2)and sum the rest of the recorrido whith a bigger mes if exist

```
equipo  mes     combustible_en_tanque   recorrido   tipo_de_recorrido
7   2011-07-01  4   100     2
7   2011-07-01  4   100     2
7   2011-08-01  4   193900  1
7   2011-09-01  4   194000  1  <- the last row of type 1 194000
7   2011-10-01  4   100     2   +=100
7   2011-11-01  4   100     2   +=100 
7   2011-12-01  4   100     2   +=100
7   2012-01-01  7   150     2   +=150
7   2012-02-01  4   50  2       +=50
```

Its returns:

```
equipo  ultimo_odometro
   7     195150
```

but if:

```
7   2011-07-01  4   100     2
7   2011-07-01  4   100     2
7   2011-08-01  4   193900  1
7   2011-09-01  4   194000  1  <- the last row of type 1 194000
no more rows whit type!=(1,2)
```

must return  194000 but the join fails.

Comment: You could also accomplish with a `UNION` of the last (1,3) record and the rest of the records as a subquery, then sum all the values.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can move conditions from the `WHERE` clause to the `LEFT JOIN`'s `ON` clause:

```
LEFT
JOIN `cierre_mensual`
  ON last_odometro.`equipo` = cierre_mensual.`equipo`
 AND cierre_mensual.mes > last_odometro.mes
 AND cierre_mensual.mes < '2012-03-01'
```